# Mina-whenever 1.0.1 - Unresolved issue with environment and command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever

I have been struggling for a number of days, trying to deploy an update to my Rails 5.2 application using `mina`.  I am trying to create an automated backup of my production database and am currently doing this using:
`mina 1.2.3`, `whenever 0.10.0` and `mina-whenever 1.0.1`.

When I run `mina deploy` I get the error message:

```
-----> Update crontab for <my_server_ip>_production
bash: line 156: bundle: command not found
! ERROR: Deploy failed.`
```

Having read around a bit, I eventually discovered that there is an open issue on the current release of `mina-whenever`, matching exactly what I am experiencing - [Open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina-whenever/issues/13)

I noticed there is a proposed workaround from a contributor which is accessible by adding `gem 'mina-whenever', git: 'https://github.com/Val/mina-whenever.git', branch: :add_environment_variable_support, require: false` to my `Gemfile`

This looked promising, but raises a completely new error with the `downcase` function:

```
** Execute whenever:update
mina aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
/Users/<my_username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bundler/gems/mina-whenever-78af0a48bc16/lib/mina/whenever/tasks.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

The updates to the `mina-whenever` code in the suggested workaround are provided [here](https://github.com/Val/mina-whenever/commit/78af0a48bc16546dc54fb5bc6d77a39294699cda), with the specific line causing the problem being:

```
set :whenever_environment, -> {     fetch(fetch(:environment_variable).downcase.to_sym) }
```

**Please could you suggest how I may be able to resolve this issue, other than crossing my fingers in the hope that a new release is issued and it doesn't have the same problem.  I am relatively new to Rails, so please forgive my ignorance...**